# Not hide and seek

Tags: word, wordplay

We're bored ...

> Mo: How's about a film?

Something outside please.

> Mo: Play piggy in the middle?

We don't know it!

> Mo: Who's up for a demo?

What word is clued above?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the word is:

> **SHOW**.

Mo: How's about a film?

> It's an anagram ("about") of HOW'S and a film is a show.

Mo: Play piggy in the middle?

> It's "the" middle, i.e. the middle of the, H, in SOW ("piggy") and a play is a show.

Mo: Who's up for a demo?

> It's an anagram ("up") of WHO'S and a demo is a show.

Title: Not hide and seek

> To show is the opposite of to hide.

Comment: Just wondering about the name "Mo", could it be a reference to rot13(Zvffbhev, juvpu unf gur nooerivngvba ZB naq vf gur "Fubj zr" fgngr)